# Split Pascal Case in Javascript (Certain Case)

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I've been trying to get a JavaScript regex command to turn something like **EYDLessThan5Days** into **EYD Less Than 5 Days**. Any ideas?

The code I used :

```
"EYDLessThan5Days"
    .replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1')
    .replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); });
```

Out: **E Y D Less Than5 Days**

But still give me wrong result.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try the following function, it's made to work with all kinds of strings you can throw at it. If you find any defects please point it out in the comments.

```js
function camelPad(str){ return str
    // Look for long acronyms and filter out the last letter
    .replace(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/g, ' $1 $2')
    // Look for lower-case letters followed by upper-case letters
    .replace(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
    // Look for lower-case letters followed by numbers
    .replace(/([a-zA-Z])(\d)/g, '$1 $2')
    .replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); })
    // Remove any white space left around the word
    .trim();
}

// Test cases
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(camelPad("EYDLessThan5Days")));
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(camelPad("LOLAllDayFrom10To9")));
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(camelPad("ILikeToStayUpTil9O'clock")));
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(camelPad("WhatRYouDoing?")));
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(camelPad("ABC")));
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(camelPad("ABCDEF")));
```

Comment: Thanks @djdavid98, all of my test cases can be solved by your solution.

Comment: This does not work with 3 letter acronyms like 'ABC' it converts it to 'AB C'

Comment: @Superdumbell Check my edit, i believe it does what you need.

Answer (score 14):

This will work for you

```
"EYDLessThan5Days".replace(/([A-Z][a-z])/g,' $1').replace(/(\d)/g,' $1');
```

will give you **"EYD Less Than 5 Days"**

## What I am doing here

```
replace(/([A-Z][a-z])/g,' $1')
```

If a Upper case letter followed by lower case letters, add space before that

```
replace(/(\d)/g,' $1')
```

If there is a number add space before that.

Comment: The only issue I see with your answer is that the op only provided the string as an example, and while your code does work for that one specific example, it would fail if the string was `"It'sOver9000And1"`, turning it into `"It's Over 9000 And1"` due to the missing `g` flag, but if you were to add it, then it would become `"It's Over 9 0 0 0 And 1"`. It does work as long as only 1 number is present in the string, but another case where it will fail would be `"IAmAGuy"`, leaving the `I` and `A` alone, because it is not followed by a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 4):

Was looking for solution and stumbled upon this post. Ended up using lodash.

For those who don't want to use Regex, there is a method in lodash library called "startCase"

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#startCase

```
_.startCase('EYDLessThan5Days'); // "EYD Less Than 5 Days"
```

Comment: And for those that don't want to `npm i lodash` just for this **function.** [`npm i lodash.startcase`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.startcase)