# c# String - Split Pascal Case

Tags: c#, regex, string

I've been trying to get a C# regex command to turn something like

```
EYDLessThan5Days
```

into

```
EYD Less Than 5 Days
```

Any ideas?

The code I used :

```
public static string SplitPascalCase(this string value) {
    Regex NameExpression = new Regex("([A-Z]+(?=$|[A-Z][a-z])|[A-Z]?[a-z0-9]+)",
                                     RegexOptions.Compiled);
    return NameExpression.Replace(value, " $1").Trim();
}
```

Out:

```
EYD Less Than5 Days
```

But still give me wrong result.

Actually I already asked about this in javascript code but when i implemented in c# code with same logic, it's failed.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: i think he don't want to separate 5.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for - you were given very detailed answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188882/split-pascal-case-in-javascript-certain-case, instead of directly converting it to C# you somewhat randomly combined parts and now looking for some sort of help. I recommend you to perform direct conversion and than ask for "how to combine following regular expression" (if you could not do it yourself). Also consider keeping quality of sample code comparable to one in that answer - regular expressions without comments are mostly unreadable.

Comment: Its as simple as removing any reference to [0-9] and putting it in a separate alternation. See @AmitJoki regex `([A-Z]+(?=$|[A-Z][a-z])|[A-Z]?[a-z]+|[0-9]+)`

Answer (score 5):

Use lookarounds in your regex so that it won't consume any characters and it allows overlapping of matches.

```
(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[0-9]?[A-Z])
```

Replace the matched boundaries with a space.

```
Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[0-9]?[A-Z])", " ");
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xU9vI3/7)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])` Matches the boundary which was exists inbetween an upper or lowercase letter and an Uppercase letter which was immediately followed by a lowercase letter. For example. consider this `ABc` string. And this regex would match, the boundary exists inbetween `A` and `Bc`. For this `aBc` example , this  regex would match, the boundary exists inbetween `a` and `Bc`
- `|` Logical OR operator.
- `(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[0-9]?[A-Z])` Matches the boundary which was exists inbetween an lower case letter or digit and an optional digit which was immediately followed by an Uppercase letter. For example. consider this `a9A` string. And this regex would match, the boundary exists inbetween `a` and `9A` , and also the boundary exists inbetween `9` and `A`, because we gave `[0-9]` as optional in positive lookahead.

Comment: yep.OP's expected output is `EYD Less Than5 Days`

Comment: regex must be (?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z]|[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z]) for 55 days senario

Answer (score 1):

You can just match and join..

```
var arr = Regex.Matches(str, @"[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][a-z]+)|\d|[A-Z][a-z]+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ",arr));
```

The regex isn't complex at all, it is just capturing each and joining them with a `" "`

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/iognqs)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do

```
string pattern=@"(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)|(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])";
Regex.Replace(input,pattern," ");
```

Comment: Please consider matching quality of your answer to one given to OP on JavaScript version. Regular expression without comments is mostly useless for future readers.